# Is it possible to make CGO generate cross-platform headers?

Tags: go, cross-platform, header-files, cgo

This is the prologue of the header CGO generated:

```
#ifndef GO_CGO_PROLOGUE_H
#define GO_CGO_PROLOGUE_H

typedef signed char GoInt8;
typedef unsigned char GoUint8;
typedef short GoInt16;
typedef unsigned short GoUint16;
typedef int GoInt32;
typedef unsigned int GoUint32;
typedef long long GoInt64;
typedef unsigned long long GoUint64;
typedef GoInt64 GoInt;
typedef GoUint64 GoUint;
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ GoUintptr;
typedef float GoFloat32;
typedef double GoFloat64;
typedef float _Complex GoComplex64;
typedef double _Complex GoComplex128;
```

Now, trying to compile with MSVC, which has no clue as to what `__SIZE_TYPE__` is or `_Complex` is not going to fly.  I could probably come up with an extra header that covers these discrepancies, but I don't know what else does CGO header generator has up its sleeve.

Comment: AFAIK, MSVC is not supported.

Comment: @JimB I've managed to compile this with MinGW after some editing, but now I have a bunch of linking errors trying to link DLL compiled with MinGW from MSVC.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with MSVC at all. I think since it's not a supported target, you may need to create an appropriate header yourself.